# Composer not installed - ansible

Tags: ansible, composer-php, vagrant

I am working on MAC OS. I am trying to install composer with an Ansible role, but composer is not found when I run the command to check composer version. ( I tried also to get the composer role from geerlingguy but no chance)

It's like the file is not even downloaded. Here is my task :

```
- name: install composer
  shell: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
  args:
    creates: /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I tried also:

```
- name: download composer
  get_url:
    url: https://getcomposer.org/installer
    dest: /tmp/installer
  tags: composer
```

Before going further, after run this task, I just went in my vagrant via `vagrant ssh`to check if the file has been downloaded and the file did not exist.

ansible : 2.8.5
vagrant : 2.2.5

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the issue. Nothing wrong with this role. I had an issue on my Vagrantfile. Actually, none roles worked.